# is that possible to get spliced value array of objects using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I have  stored the values in an array,

```
const greens = [
  { name: "cedar", count: 2 },
  { name: "fir", count: 6 },
  { name: "pine", count: 3 }
];

var greensSplice = greens.splice(0,1);
```

when I splice to remove the initial index value and change the position of the index, I wish to get the removed index value

Comment: what should be the expected result here? You should add in the question itself...

Comment: The first argument you pass to `splice` is the index at which the element(s) are to be removed or added. So if you do `splice(1`, the index at which you're removing is 1. So either repeat the 1 or save it in a variable.

Comment: i understood your question using, it's very simple, Just check the console on 
greenSplice
After you get this value
[ { name: "fir", count: 6 },
  { name: "pine", count: 3 }
]